# Titanium Appcelerator - getting JSON in reverse order

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, titanium-mobile

I have a JSON as in example: (server side)

```
myJSON = {
       "details":[
           {"ui":"3"},
           {"vi":"7"},
           {"p" :"c:\"}
       ],
       "flowers":[
           {"bla"},
           {"bla"},
           {"bla"},
       ],
       "examples":[
       ]
};
```

Now in the Titanium I'm pulling this JSON:

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.onerror = function(e){
                  Ti.API.error('Bad Server =>' + e.error);
          }

    xhr.open('POST', 'http://.....');
    xhr.send();

    xhr.onload = function(){
                 response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
             }
```

Now, when I'm trying to alert the "response" value, I see something like this:

```
 myJSON = {
       "examples":[
       ],
       "flowers":[
           {"bla"},
           {"bla"},
           {"bla"},
       ],
       "details":[
           {"ui":"3"},
           {"vi":"7"},
           {"p" :"c:\"}
       ],
};
```

Is anybody can give me an idea why is it reversed?

Comment: You need to escape the backslash from `c:\\`

Answer (score 3):

The order of properties is not guaranteed or significant in JSON (or JavaScript literal notation, or JavaScript objects in general). These objects are equivalent:

```
{
   "one": 1,
   "two": 2
}
```

and

```
{
   "two": 2,
   "one": 1
}
```

(You also need to escape the `\` in `{"p" :"c:\"}`, e.g.: `{"p" :"c:\\"}`.)

To maintain order, you have to use an *array*, as you have for your `details` and `flowers` values (note that they have not been reversed).

Also, note that what you've quoted isn't JSON. The giveaway is the `myJSON = ...` at the beginning of it. What you've quoted is an assignment statement using JavaScript object literal notation (e.g., an object initializer) for the right-hand side.